# php basic send input field values

Tags: php

I am brand new to php and have been fiddling with sending emails based off what is within a input field. I can get the email to send, but cant get the data within the input field to show up in email. Any suggestions.

I tried tying the variable name to the id  $comments = comments etc
but i just get blank emails. Any pointers

```js
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {
  
  //Email information
  $admin_email = "info@email.com";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
  $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];

  
 $name = $_GET['name'];
  //send email
  mail($admin_email, "$name", $comment, "From:" . $email);
  
  //Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }
mail("info@email.com","$name",$comment);
?>
```

```html
<div id="contact" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
  <h2 class="text-center">CONTACT</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <p>Contact me and I'll get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> </p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> </p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Run Script" id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: your php code is looking for the id `comment`. Your HTML markup has the id `comments`

Comment: Why not just use post variables?

Comment: @Luke You mean name, not id.

Comment: @Mikey thanks. I always do that

Comment: Do you have a form tag?

Answer (score 2):

Your textarea html has name attribute **comments**

```
 <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
```

but you use to get that information by **$_REQUEST['comment']** which is not there.

```
replace $_REQUEST['comment'] with $_REQUEST['comments']
```

**Edit**

Replace your html with below code and see is the inputed information is populating or not once you hit submit button.

```
<?php
 print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
<div id="contact" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
  <h2 class="text-center">CONTACT</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <p>Contact me and I'll get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> </p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> </p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> </p>
    </div>
    <form  action="" method="get">
    <div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Run Script" id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: changed it to comments but no luck

Comment: doesn help. the email no longer sends.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
```

here name=comments
so your form should be

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form"/>
    <div id="contact" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
      <h2 class="text-center">CONTACT</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <p>Contact me and I'll get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
          <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> </p>
          <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> </p>
          <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
              <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
              <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Run Script" id="submit" name="btn_submit" type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>


 <?php
```

//your email is required so users always fill that field.so if user click button

```
 if (isset($_POST['btn_submit']))  {

      //Email information
      $admin_email = "info@email.com";
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $name = $_POST['name'];


        $comment = $_POST['comments'];//replace here comments


     $name =$_POST['name'];
      //send email
      mail($admin_email, $name, $comment, "From:" . $email);

      //Email response
      echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
      }
    mail("info@email.com",$name,$comment);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your html code should be wrap with form tag

Like

```
<form name="form_name" >
   // HTML code goes here
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use form to get data after submit.

Method can be either `get` or `post`, but here you are using request and get so you have to use the get in form tag's method attribute like this.

`<form method="get">`

change your code with following.

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

  //Email information
  $admin_email = "info@email.com";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
  $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];


 $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
  //send email
  mail($admin_email, "$name", $comment, "From:" . $email);

  //Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }
mail("info@email.com","$name",$comment);
?>


<div id="contact" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
  <h2 class="text-center">CONTACT</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <p>Contact me and I'll get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> </p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> </p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> </p>
    </div>
    <form method="get">
    <div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Run Script" id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: email still blank

Comment: Use `var_dump($_GET)` to see if all fields contain the values or not?

Comment: change `$comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];` to `$comment = $_REQUEST['comments'];`, because it will cause a undefined index comment warning since you were using `name="comments"` in your `<textarea>` so you've to use `comments` not `comment`